# MutationObserver fails to observe textarea

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm trying to add custom undo operations to a textarea element by using a MutationObserver object.  I've looked on MDN for how to use this object, and as far as I know I seem to be using it correctly.  However, none of the mutations are registering - I want to observe whenever the text in the textarea changes.

```
function initObserver() {
    var editorObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        console.log("MUTATION");

        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            console.log(mutation.type);
        });
    });

    var editorObserverConfig = { characterData: true };

    var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");

    editorObserver.observe(editor, editorObserverConfig);
}

initObserver();
```

What might be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest approach would be to use `oninput` event

```
var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
editor.oninput = function(e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I guess this is suitable for what I'm doing.

Comment: Is there an alternative to input that acts more like a text editor would?  IE, instead of listening to every character, is there an event that bundles up characters and fires once?

Comment: _"is there an event that bundles up characters and fires once?_  Tried `onchange` event ? What is expected result ?

Comment: onchange only fires if focus is lost from the textarea.  I want the undo action to behave normally when the last action was inputting regular text, but override what happens when tab is pressed (insert a tab character instead of jumping between elements, among other things).  If I listen to the tab events and the input events, I get a lot of input events and I don't know how to predict what the browser is going to do with them, so I can't just remove them all at once.

Comment: Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? Replace characters in `textarea` `oninput` ? Tried `console.log(e)` within `oninput` handler ? Could try to use `e.preventDefault()` , `e.keyCode` to filter which key was pressed , replace characters ?

Comment: Your answer might be a good alternative to the above problem but real question was , whats wrong with the given mutationObserver code?
I am facing same issue with the mutationObserve it observes all other mutation but not working for characterData.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question as to what is wrong with that code mutation observers observe changes to the DOM. Value changes to a form element are not reflected by the DOM so would not trigger the mutation observer.

So in short there is nothing wrong with that code. But you aren't changing the DOM when you enter text into a text area.

Comment: But characterData property is for detecting changes in text inside a node according to this... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/characterData

I got an example tutorial in which characterData is working, you can see here 
https://codepen.io/impressivewebs/pen/aXrzex?editors=0011

Comment: @iamatulK character data is not the same as the value property. The value property is not reflected in the DOM. CharacterData of a node is but again characterData is not the same as the value property of a DOM element. You cannot use mutation observers to monitor value changes.

Comment: @iamatulK As I said in answer "Value changes to a form element are not reflected by the DOM" but your example is using a content editable paragraph element. They are two completely different scenarios. A node's content is different than a form element's value property.